# AngularJS SearchBox typeahead not working

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I've been trying to make a searchbox typeahead using [Bootstrap Angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), copying exactly how it is on their website and worked perfectly on notepad++ but not on visual studio 2013. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="../../Content/angularjs/example.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../../Content/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
```

The browser does not display any library reference problem ... but I think that I might be missing something.

At first, Visual Studio wasn't recognizing the attribute uib-typeahead-match,index,match,query,template-url but then I changed to data-uib-typeahead,... then the unrecognized mark disappeared.

Full code:
index.html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }

  .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper > .message {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #868686;
  }

  .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper > .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    min-width: 160px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
  <a>
      <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
      <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  </a>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html">
  <div class="custom-popup-wrapper"
     ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}"
     style="display: block;"
     ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress"
     aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
    <p class="message">select location from drop down.</p>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
      <li class="uib-typeahead-match" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }"
        ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
        <div data-uib-typeahead-match data-index="$index" data-match="match" data-query="query" data-template-url="templateUrl"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>

<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

    <h4>Static arrays</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

example.js:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var _selected;

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
  // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously
  $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.data.results.map(function(item){
        return item.formatted_address;
      });
    });
  };

  $scope.ngModelOptionsSelected = function(value) {
    if (arguments.length) {
      _selected = value;
    } else {
      return _selected;
    }
  };

  $scope.modelOptions = {
    debounce: {
      default: 500,
      blur: 250
    },
    getterSetter: true
  };

  $scope.statesWithFlags = [{'name':'Alabama','flag':'5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png'},{'name':'Alaska','flag':'e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/43px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png'},{'name':'Arizona','flag':'9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png'},{'name':'Arkansas','flag':'9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arkansas.svg.png'},{'name':'California','flag':'0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png'},{'name':'Colorado','flag':'4/46/Flag_of_Colorado.svg/45px-Flag_of_Colorado.svg.png'},{'name':'Connecticut','flag':'9/96/Flag_of_Connecticut.svg/39px-Flag_of_Connecticut.svg.png'},{'name':'Delaware','flag':'c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png'},{'name':'Florida','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png'},{'name':'Georgia','flag':'5/54/Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg.png'},{'name':'Hawaii','flag':'e/ef/Flag_of_Hawaii.svg/46px-Flag_of_Hawaii.svg.png'},{'name':'Idaho','flag':'a/a4/Flag_of_Idaho.svg/38px-Flag_of_Idaho.svg.png'},{'name':'Illinois','flag':'0/01/Flag_of_Illinois.svg/46px-Flag_of_Illinois.svg.png'},{'name':'Indiana','flag':'a/ac/Flag_of_Indiana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Indiana.svg.png'},{'name':'Iowa','flag':'a/aa/Flag_of_Iowa.svg/44px-Flag_of_Iowa.svg.png'},{'name':'Kansas','flag':'d/da/Flag_of_Kansas.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kansas.svg.png'},{'name':'Kentucky','flag':'8/8d/Flag_of_Kentucky.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kentucky.svg.png'},{'name':'Louisiana','flag':'e/e0/Flag_of_Louisiana.svg/46px-Flag_of_Louisiana.svg.png'},{'name':'Maine','flag':'3/35/Flag_of_Maine.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maine.svg.png'},{'name':'Maryland','flag':'a/a0/Flag_of_Maryland.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maryland.svg.png'},{'name':'Massachusetts','flag':'f/f2/Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg/46px-Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg.png'},{'name':'Michigan','flag':'b/b5/Flag_of_Michigan.svg/45px-Flag_of_Michigan.svg.png'},{'name':'Minnesota','flag':'b/b9/Flag_of_Minnesota.svg/46px-Flag_of_Minnesota.svg.png'},{'name':'Mississippi','flag':'4/42/Flag_of_Mississippi.svg/45px-Flag_of_Mississippi.svg.png'},{'name':'Missouri','flag':'5/5a/Flag_of_Missouri.svg/46px-Flag_of_Missouri.svg.png'},{'name':'Montana','flag':'c/cb/Flag_of_Montana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Montana.svg.png'},{'name':'Nebraska','flag':'4/4d/Flag_of_Nebraska.svg/46px-Flag_of_Nebraska.svg.png'},{'name':'Nevada','flag':'f/f1/Flag_of_Nevada.svg/45px-Flag_of_Nevada.svg.png'},{'name':'New Hampshire','flag':'2/28/Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg.png'},{'name':'New Jersey','flag':'9/92/Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg.png'},{'name':'New Mexico','flag':'c/c3/Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg.png'},{'name':'New York','flag':'1/1a/Flag_of_New_York.svg/46px-Flag_of_New_York.svg.png'},{'name':'North Carolina','flag':'b/bb/Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg.png'},{'name':'North Dakota','flag':'e/ee/Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg/38px-Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg.png'},{'name':'Ohio','flag':'4/4c/Flag_of_Ohio.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ohio.svg.png'},{'name':'Oklahoma','flag':'6/6e/Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg/45px-Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg.png'},{'name':'Oregon','flag':'b/b9/Flag_of_Oregon.svg/46px-Flag_of_Oregon.svg.png'},{'name':'Pennsylvania','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg/45px-Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg.png'},{'name':'Rhode Island','flag':'f/f3/Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg/32px-Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg.png'},{'name':'South Carolina','flag':'6/69/Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg.png'},{'name':'South Dakota','flag':'1/1a/Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg/46px-Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg.png'},{'name':'Tennessee','flag':'9/9e/Flag_of_Tennessee.svg/46px-Flag_of_Tennessee.svg.png'},{'name':'Texas','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Texas.svg.png'},{'name':'Utah','flag':'f/f6/Flag_of_Utah.svg/45px-Flag_of_Utah.svg.png'},{'name':'Vermont','flag':'4/49/Flag_of_Vermont.svg/46px-Flag_of_Vermont.svg.png'},{'name':'Virginia','flag':'4/47/Flag_of_Virginia.svg/44px-Flag_of_Virginia.svg.png'},{'name':'Washington','flag':'5/54/Flag_of_Washington.svg/46px-Flag_of_Washington.svg.png'},{'name':'West Virginia','flag':'2/22/Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg/46px-Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg.png'},{'name':'Wisconsin','flag':'2/22/Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg/45px-Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg.png'},{'name':'Wyoming','flag':'b/bc/Flag_of_Wyoming.svg/43px-Flag_of_Wyoming.svg.png'}];
});
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I don't get any error on browser console but the searchbox simply doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide the full code of searchbox? So I can check if it's working or not.

Comment: sure, check my new edit

Comment: If you test it on notepad++ it will work but not on visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I couldn't solve this problem because angular bootstrap classes was in conflict with adminLTE's so I had to create my own angular script for typeahead.